# How to migrate "project" in Serverless 0.X to Serverless 1.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I once used Serverless 0.X frameworks and have some of my own projects with it.   After that, I have a long blank period for half year or so, and I back to Serverless 1.0.

In Serverless 0.X, we have the concept of "project", which can handle many functions under same environment. But in Serverless 1.X, "project" looks retired, only one "handler.js" under root folder.

How can I handle many functions under same environment? Should I code all functions within one handler.js?

And how can I avoid 50MB limits of each functions? In Serverless 0.X, it is easy to avoid this limitation, because each function uploaded separately, but I don't know how to avoid this limitation in Serverless 1.X.

Including these questions, are there any good documentation for migrating Serverless 0.X projects to Serverless 1.X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From official docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/v0_to_v1):

> #### How to upgrade from 0.x to 1.x
>
> As Serverless 1.x is a complete reimplementation and does not
>   implement all the features that were in 0.x (but has a lot more
>   features in general) there is no direct update path. Basically the
>   best way for users to move from 0.x to 1.x is to go through our guide
>   and the AWS provider documentation that will teach you all the details
>   of Serverless 1.x. This should make it pretty easy to understand how
>   to set up a service for 1.x and move your code over. We've worked with
>   different teams during the Beta phase of Serverless 1.x and they were
>   able to move their services into the new release pretty quickly.

Now, answering your questions:

> How can I handle many functions under same environment? Should I code
>   all functions within one handler.js?

You need to take a look in this [blog post](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-architecture-code-patterns/) about serverless architectures. The answer is that you don't need to use only one function. You can have multiple functions. Also, the **handler.js** file don't need to have this name and it don't need to be in the root folder. See the following **serverless.yml** example.

```
service: my-storage

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3

functions:
  my-photos:
    handler: lib/photos.handlePhotos
    events:
      - http: GET photos
      - http: POST photos
      - http: PUT photos
      - http: DELETE photos
      - http: OPTIONS photos
  my-videos:
    handler: lib/videos.handleVideos
    events:
      - http: GET videos
      - http: POST videos
      - http: PUT videos
      - http: DELETE videos
      - http: OPTIONS videos
```

In this example, we have two files inside a **lib** folder: **photos.js** and **videos.js**. Each file has a function (**handlePhotos** / **handleVideos**) that is responsible to handle API gateway events.

> And how can I avoid 50MB limits of each functions?

Use multiple functions.